# Echo out string from PHP Variable, within comments

Tags: php

I have some (simplified) PHP config for a DB connection.

```
<?php
/* 
<CONFIG application="Example" version="1.1">
    <Database>
        <Driver>MYSQL</Driver>
        <Host>http://example.com</Host>
        <Port>3306</Port>
        <Database>qwerty</Database>
        <Username>usr</Username>
        <Password>hackme</Password>
    </Database>
</CONFIG>
*/
?>
```

How can I populate the host, in the comments with a variable from an array, `$serv["host"]`

Here's my attempt...

```
<?php $serv["host"] = "http://example.com"; ?>

<?php
/* 
<CONFIG application="Example" version="1.1">
    <Database>
        <Driver>MYSQL</Driver>
        <Host>$serv["host"]</Host>
        <Port>3306</Port>
        <Database>qwerty</Database>
        <Username>usr</Username>
        <Password>hackme</Password>
    </Database>
</CONFIG>
*/
?>
```

I've tried various concatenation and echo combinations, but it either doesn't compile properly or prints out my DB connection details. I need to keep these comments because the code I'm editing seems to require it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to echo things in a comment. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want to edit the php script you are actually running? That sounds like a very bad idea, just fill in the values you need where you need them. Are you sure you don't need to output valid xml to set up the database connection?

Comment: The MySQL server config file in the web app I have sits in the comments like in my example. For some reason it only works like this. I am modifying the DB config php file to look up a host value from another centralised place. I could refactor the whole thing, but it's just this small change I need. BUt the commenting is problematic for me.

Comment: I disagree. The config file is as it is. It should be enough to say that it needs to keep its format. The challenge is to keep it in comments, and dynamically update the host.

Comment: @jeroen et al. I don't have functional access (without a complete assessment of code beyond my capability) to the rest of the web application. I only know of, and can edit this config file. removing the comments makes it fail. It shouldn't matter. My question is about populating config embedded in comments. Whether you think it's good practice is irrelevant. My question is useful for anyone else wanting to do the same. Whether you think there is a real world use for it or not. I thought this was a site for people with specific coding questions and attempts at solving it. I broke the rules how?

Comment: @jeroen I second square_eyes. I don't see why this question should be off-topic. He asked for a solution to a coding problem of his. Though it would be nice to see the background of the problem it is not necessary to solve the problem and irrelevant to the question. Unanswerable is definitively not the case since two people already provided answers. If he had asked to write a limerick between PHP comments it'd still be a valid coding problem and noone would have the right to question his reasons. Closing really seems rather arbitrary here.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user I originally close-voted as I think the question is unclear, see my question above. And what is supposed to happen if you rewrite the script you are running? And lastly, if that is the only file you can change, why not put the values at the correct place to start with?

Comment: @jeroen That's all right. I see your points. But this is just not relevant. See my limerick comment above. We don't have to know that to answer his question. What he provides is a valid problem that can be answered. You can very well point out security or practicability issues you see without closing the whole thing. Programmatically writing into comments can have an application and here you could learn how to do it. There's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @some-non-descript-user If I think a question is unclear, I would think that is relevant to me :-) And apart from that, echoing out things in php only changes what is shown when the script is run, it does not affect the script itself and it would seem that the database setup parses the script instead of running it as there is no output if you put everything in comments. Still unclear as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @jeroen Looks like we won't come to a consensus here. You have higher standards of clarity than me. :-)

Comment: The code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mastacheata/3a1480b1317a37531009) is used to instantiate a ZF1 DB Adapter from the XML supplied.
The Class is from library/Common/Database.php and the actual execution stuff is from config/config.php (All from the SpacialAudio SAM Broadcaster Pro php template)

https://gist.github.com/mastacheata/3a1480b1317a37531009

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$serv = array(
    'host' => 'http://example.com';
);
?>

<CONFIG application="Example" version="1.1">
    <Database>
        <Driver>MYSQL</Driver>
        <Host><?php echo $serv['host']; ?></Host>
        <Port>3306</Port>
        <Database>qwerty</Database>
        <Username>usr</Username>
        <Password>hackme</Password>
    </Database>
</CONFIG>
```

Comment: Accessing the file directly with this solution would print out my db connection details for anyone to see

Comment: Where to put files is not what this question is about.

Answer (score 0):

You could make PHP create a file consisting of your commented out (out-commented?) code and include it then.

```
<?php $serv["host"] = "http://example.com"; ?>

<?php
$dbcon = "
/* 
<CONFIG application="Example" version="1.1">
    <Database>
        <Driver>MYSQL</Driver>
        <Host>" . $serv["host"] . "</Host>
        <Port>3306</Port>
        <Database>qwerty</Database>
        <Username>usr</Username>
        <Password>hackme</Password>
    </Database>
</CONFIG>
*/";
$f = fopen("comment.php", 'w');
fwrite($f, $dbcon);
fclose($f);
include("comment.php");

?>
```

You might have to adjust destination and include paths as well as file system permissions, of course. Make sure that it's not readable/guessable from the document root, though. 
I'd be interested to hear if that actually works.

Comment: I had thought about this, and it's a creative solution. But I wonder if it's unnecessary load on the server to be writing files for every hit on the page that requires this database connection?

Comment: I don't think that would have much impact. But that depends on your load, of course. You might want to modify filenames by the different hostnames, maybe, and only write a new file if a new hostname is necessary? (`if(file_exists(...))`)

Comment: Funny solution but I don't think that will work: If you run the script and include the file, there will be nothing there as only comments result in no output. And when you parse the file, you will only see the source: The original php and the include statement. The OP would have to parse the generated file to get the database connection. And you should include an opening php tag in the string as otherwise everybody will see the login data when `comment.php` is opened directly.